# How to correct values diverging from reality

Tags: functions

I have two systems measuring the same thing: the state of charge (SoC) of a battery. The range is from 0 to 100%. One system seems to be correct, and shows a higher SoC of 30%, when the other systems shows 25%, when the battery is discharged. Also, on the other side of the SoC (as in fully charged), the 'incorrect systems' jumps the last 5% from 95 to 100 when fully charged.
In the middle part of the 'curve', both systems converge to the same numbers.

So, one could say, one curve (the correct one) is linear, while the other is a curve (lower at the bottom and top end).

My idea is to apply a formula, that can correct the curve-based values to the linear values.

My maths is rusty at best (or maybe never existed to the level to solve this problem) ... a glimpse left thinks, whether this is an y = mx + b problem?

Any help / hint is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can collect data using the two systems simultaneously.  Let $x$ be the SoC as measured by the correct one and $f(x)$ the SoC as measured by the other.  You might do several charge/discharge cycles to verify that the data is consistent.  If not, you can assess the error.  What you are looking for is the inverse function $f^{-1}$, so you can take a $y$ value from the wrong one, compute $f^{-1}(y)$ and get the correct value (or at least something close).  If you plot your data, $f(x)$ needs to be monotonic or there will not be a well defined inverse.  Assuming it is, you can get Excel or Mathematica to fit the data with the $y$ values as the independent variable and the $x$ values as the dependent variable.  Plot the fitted function over your data and see if you like the results.  You get to choose the order of the fit if it is polynomial, or a log or exponential function.